# v-for vuejs como carregar com temporizador

Tags: vue.js

Como consigo que a exibição da lista se torne pausada,

exemplo 
espera 1 segundo
exibe:

> ```
> 1 
> + 1 segundo
> 2
> + 1 segundo
> 3
> ```

```
<div>
  <span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }} </span>
</div>
```

usei o setTimeout no created mais não deu certo.

Comment: Creio que isso possa te ajudar https://medium.com/byteconf/building-a-pomodoro-timer-with-vue-js-on-codepen-ec9d1d53e833

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para controlares isso tens de mudar o que o Vue usa para iterar, ou seja cria uma array e vai mudando a array à velocidade que precisas para ter o efeito desejado:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      arr: arr.slice(0, 1),
      showUpTo: 1,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.showUpTo++;
      this.arr = arr.slice(0, this.showUpTo);
      if (this.showUpTo === arr.length) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <p v-for="n in arr">{{ n }} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

A mesma coisa mas com uma propriedade `computed`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      showUpTo: 1,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    arr() {
      return arr.slice(0, this.showUpTo);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.showUpTo++;
      if (this.showUpTo === arr.length) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <p v-for="n in arr">{{ n }} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente reposta, fiquei tentando imaginar como seria uma resposta para esse pergunta, quase cheguei a dizer que dá forma que ele estava tentando isso seria impossível.

Comment: +1 Vim na esperança de criar uma resposta, mas não vejo uma forma mais clara e simples que a sua :D